# SQL SERVER query cursor with dynamic LinkedServer

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I want to monitor few SQL SERVER instances (about 31), and I want to prepare a procedure that will aggregate data from instances based on sys.servers list, but I cant dynamically ask a server.

```
DECLARE @instance_name sysname;
DECLARE instance_cursor CURSOR FOR
select data_source from sys.servers where is_linked = 1;

OPEN instance_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM instance_cursor INTO @instance_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --Do something on a linked server
    SELECT 1 FROM @instance_name.master.sys.master_files


    FETCH NEXT FROM instance_cursor INTO @instance_name
END
CLOSE instance_cursor
DEALLOCATE instance_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master
GO

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#server_info') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #server_info

 CREATE TABLE #server_info 
        (
            Col1 SQL_VARIANT,
            Col2 SQL_VARIANT,
            Col3 SQL_VARIANT,
            Col4 SQL_VARIANT
        )  -- change data type as needed.

DECLARE @instance_name  NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @sql            NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE instance_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM master.sys.servers WHERE is_linked = 1 
ORDER BY name

OPEN instance_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM instance_cursor INTO @instance_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --Do something on a linked server
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #server_info (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) SELECT .... FROM ' + @instance_name + '.master.sys...'
    PRINT @sql  -- verify for your syntax
    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM instance_cursor INTO @instance_name
END
CLOSE instance_cursor
DEALLOCATE instance_cursor


SELECT * FROM #server_info
```

Comment: You really need to ensure you properly quote the dynamic objects using `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: @Larnu: it is not a necessary condition to use the QUOTENAME function for dynamic SQL. It works like a charm without it.

Comment: It *is* a necessary function to protect you against injection, and *"It works like a charm without it."* isn't true when you have object names that must be delimit identified. If the OP has a linked server called `Linked Server` your code *will* fail. Not properly quoting objects only has negative effects, and doing so only positive. There is no reason to not do it; other than to create security issue or undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not found a perfect solution for this, but:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [kk].[query_ls] 
    @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @instance_name sysname;
        DECLARE instance_cursor CURSOR FOR
        select data_source from sys.servers where is_linked = 1;

        OPEN instance_cursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM instance_cursor INTO @instance_name

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @query = REPLACE(@SQL,'#server#',@instance_name )
            EXEC (@query)

            FETCH NEXT FROM instance_cursor INTO @instance_name
        END
        CLOSE instance_cursor
        DEALLOCATE instance_cursor
END
```

And usage example:

```
EXEC    [kk].[query_ls] N'use _dba INSERT INTO kk.cpuUsagePerDB select *,getdate()  from  [#server#]._dba.kk.[V_cpuUsagePerDB]'
```

Another solution can be achieved by OPENQUERY